# Mongoose: How do I avoid callback hell whilst allowing for stubbing of mongoose methods that do not return promises?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mongoose, promise

In my express node application written in typescript, I'm using mongoose and am trying to avoid callback hell whist allowing for stubbing the mongoose functions in my mocha/sinon unit tests.

Where mongoose does not return a promise (e.g. [Model.count()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#count_count)) I'm wrapping the call in a new (awaited) promise which is resolved/rejected in the callback, like so:

```
const myModelCount = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  MyModel.count({}, (err, count) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
      return;
    }

    resolve(count);
  });
});
```

This works great but I don't know how I can unit test the containing function and avoid a timeout error due to the unresolved promise. I want to stub `MyModel.count` so that it does not attempt to call the database, but how do I stub it so that the awaited promise is resolved and the program continues?

Doing something like:

```
sinon.stub(MyModel, 'count').returns(Promise.resolve(1));
```

does not work as it does not resolve the promise that is being awaited, and since I don't have access to the `resolve`/`reject` parameters I don't know how to resolve the promise in the stub.

Is there a way I can make the above work, or alternatively how I can refactor my code to both avoid callback hell and so that I can stub out the mongoose functions in unit tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding returned promises, there seems to be a misunderstanding (easy to have with mongoose) with the model [`count`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#count_count) method. It returns a [query object](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) if called without a callback and, as with all query objects, when invoked by [`exec()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec) (also without a callback) will return a promise.

```js
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; // This sets the mongoose internal Promise to the native Promise, while it is not necessary it is highly advised.
const promise = MyModel.count().exec();
```

As far as testing, if the unit test is meant to test that a wrapper function is simply calling the wrapped function then I find this to be more of a functional test as any test should only be concerned with the inputs/outputs of a function (the API of the function) and not the inner workings (the implementation of the function). In other words the function should be a black box to any tests so that if the implementation were to change but the API remains constant then the tests should continue to pass.

That said if you really want to stub the model count/exec out then something like the following might work (pseudo coding here):

```js
sinon.stub(MyModel, 'count').returns({
  exec() { return Promise.resolve(1); }
});
```

Hope this clears up some possible confusion and helps!

Comment: Thanks Jason, it's the `exec()` function that I was missing! Regarding your point about testing, not sure I follow you. If you don't stub out functions that call integration points, how can you test the parent function returns the expected value?

Comment: It's a fuzzy line sometimes and a source of where DI comes into play to alleviate some of this. When a function includes accessing external resources I will try to ensure that any logic before and after accessing the external resources are in separate functions that are easily unit testable and then use a functional test on a composition function that combines the pre/post logic with the external request. The reason for this is that similar with using any 3rd party lib, it is assumed (and hopefully vetted) that the functionality exposed via the 3rd party lib's API is already covered.

Comment: @RichBrowne Glad to to help. Testing can be a bit confusing especially if it is done post implementation hence why TDD has seen a significant rise in popularity. Good luck!